# How to target or change ancher or its id text color, if id changing randomly on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to changing anchor, id, span or b tag text color, but it's not changing because of randomly changing id.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<a id="XgP7Wrq-1503732157576" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" style=""><span class="thin">here</span> <b>sometext</b></a>
```

Here is the JS Code:

```
var x = getElementsbyid("XgP7Wrq-1503732157576");

x.style.color = '#00FF00';
```

else if any alternative way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: There is no `getElementsbyid` function. You're probably thinking of `document.getElementById`, in which case remove the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find some *other* way to identify it, based on something that doesn't change. You haven't given us enough information for us to help you do that, but some ways are

- Where it is in the structure of the page, a compound selector could find it. For instance, if it were the first `a` element with `href="javascript:void(0)"` that's inside a `div` with class `header`, then `document.querySelector("div.header a[href='javascript:void(0)']")` would find it. Or if that `span.thin` is consistent, then `document.querySelector("a > span.thing").parentNode`.
- If there's something about the `id` that doesn't change, an attribute substring selector could work (`document.querySelector("a[href*='substring']")`).
- If it's always the 4th (or whatever) `a` element with `href="javascript:void(0)"`, you could find it based on that (`document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='javascript:void(0)']")[3]`).

...etc. The tools are:

- `document.getElementById` - But you'd have to know its `id`, so that's out.
- [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) - Find the first element that matches the given CSS selector. Can be a full selector, including a compound one. Any valid CSS selector works.
- [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) - Finds all elements that match the given CSS selector (as a list).

Comment: thanks for reply.    plz correct me. its have class name .thin and its follow by random id ex - #XgP7Wrq-1503732157576 .thin  if i target class by using ur mentioned method - document.querySelectorAll so it will works?

Comment: @BagfulInternational: Yes, if it's the first `a` element with a `span.thin` as a direct child, then: `var x = document.querySelector("a > span.thin").parentNode; x.style.color = '#00FF00';` (or just `document.querySelector("a > span.thin").parentNode.style.color = '#00FF00';`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are traversing the DOM with ID, the correct syntax is as follows,

```
var x = document.getElementById("XgP7Wrq-1503732157576");
x.style.color = "#00FF00";
```

You do not include the hashtag as argument because the method specifically looks for the ID.

Since the ID of the elements is always changing, you may do one of the followings too.

```
// Accessing the third <a> element
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[2]
// Accessing the first element with class "apple"
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("apple")[0]
```

Comment: @Nicholas -  Id changing, everytime page loads

Comment: Hey Nic,  i used ur ans in this way - var x = document.getElementsByClassName(".thin")[1]
x.style.color = "#F44336";    but not working

Comment: @BagfulInternational Similarly, you do not include the period. So, instead of `.getElementsByClassName(".thin")` it should be `.getElementsByClassName("thin")`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `class`

```
<a id="XgP7Wrq-1503732157576" class="myclass" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" style=""><span class="thin">here</span> <b>sometext</b></a>
```

Code js:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
//for first anchor
x[0].style.color = "#00FF00";
//for all
for(var i=0; i<= x.length; i++)
{
x[i].style.color = "#00FF00";
}
```

Comment: There is no class on the `a` in the question. I suspect if the OP had control over the page in question, they wouldn't need to solve the changing-`id` problem.